# Extract value from array in datafactory

Tags: azure-data-factory

how can I extract the value of the Name element from the following array in datafactory:

{
"variableName": "PiQuality",
"value": {
"Value": {
"Value": {
"Name": "vaCurrent"
}
}
}
}

Thankyou so much.

Answer (score 1):

So I just tried this, created a string variable called "try" and set it with your example json. Then I set a second string variable with the following value:

@json(variables('try')).value.Value.Value.Name

So this first converts the string to a json, and then navigates the properties until it gets to the one you are looking for.

[image: Debug output]